# Custom shader socket type

Tags: python, shader-nodes

I just created a node group using python with some sockets with different socket type, Now some types are missed, for example drop down list to have some option for the group. to solve this I temporary used int type to select number to select options, for example 0 for option1 and 1 for option 2 ,... and some text socket to show some helps. But this a nasty way. My question is: is it possible to create a custom (shader group) node socket (dropdown list) using python?

Comment: you can only use implemented socket types as far as I know. This means you can use e.g. a pink boolean socket, or a dark green integer socket, or light green geometry socket or an 'empty' socket used for creating inputs/outputs conveniently etc.

Comment: enum sockets are in the works but I doubt you can create them with the python API. see https://devtalk.blender.org/t/enum-sockets-proposal/21318

Comment: Just to clarify: you can use geometry nodes socket types in a shader. At least some will correctly transmit data as a float, and some may crash Blender.